# Azure machine language tutorial step failed

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I'm following the steps defined in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/preview/tutorial-classifying-iris-part-3

I issued the command line:
**az ml env set -n myenv -g myenvrg**

Got the error:
*Resource with group myenvrg and name myenv cannot be set, as its provisioning state is Failed. Provisioning state succeeded is required.*

Any ideas why I get this error and any workaround?

Comment: Can you run `az ml env show -g myenvrg -n myenv`?

Comment: {
  "Cluster Name": "myenv",
  "Cluster Size": "N/A",
  "Created On": "2017-11-24T02:35:58.34099999999999997Z",
  "Location": "westcentralus",
  "Provisioning State": "Failed",
  "Resource Group": "myenvrg",
  "Subscription": "a2afdb46-b8d8-447d-9838-0128e0225f84"
}

Comment: Maybe you should re-setup a new resource group and env, please try it.

Comment: I assume this resource group and env are used to setup the web service endpoint in docker for predicting results? It need not be the same resource group used for experimentation?

Comment: az ml env setup -n myenvtwo --location westcentralus failed again.

I can send Output of az ml env show -g myenvtworg -n myenvtwo by other means if it will help. I couldn't post due to edit box limits.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue. I deleted the az ml env by using:

```
az ml env delete -g resourcegroup -n envname
```

I then recreated the az ml env but this time I specified the resource group the az ml env was to be created in. In my case I chose the resource group that the model management component was located in.

```
az ml env setup -n envname -g rgwithmodelmanager --location westcentralus
```

This time the az ml env created successfully. You can see the status of it with

```
az ml env show -g rgwithmodelmanager -n envname
```

Comment: If I follow the steps you mentioned, I get an error.. "BadRequestFormat: The request format was invalid. Details: Updating property 'Properties.StorageAccount.ResourceId' is not supported."